# TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetById in object Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to have an automatic email machine, without having to write all of the messages and email addresses myself.

I'm really new to this, so please don't be too harsh.

```
function sendOrder() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to send the order?',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var deliveryDate = ui.prompt('Delivery date:');

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetById('1pON34oXVhlpC8goyBxfu6-Gw92tgQBUVUpskZUtgp4E');
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
    var range = s.getRange('A1:C102');
    var to = "example@example.com";
    var body = '';
    var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
    var body = "Here is the table:<br/><br/>" +
      htmlTable +
      "<br/><br/>The end."
    MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'Subject', body, {
      htmlBody: body
    });
  };
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Yeah! Your order has been sent :)');
}
```

I just expect this to give me a box to enter a date, once the date is entered it should say it has sent and our supplier will see all of the orders.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

This is because function `getSheetById()` does not exist.

---

#### Solution:

Use `openById()` instead:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('yourIdHere');
```

---

#### Reference:

- [`openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

Comment: Now it's says that SheetConverter is not defined... How to define it? On other script it's running without any problems without any other lines

Comment: Try googling it, first thing I found was [this article](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter). Looks like you need to enable the library.

Comment: You were right, thank you very much about that. Now I just have a problem with sending a blank table, but I'm wondering, can I attach a xlsx file in the email so it'll attach a file, instead of reading all table and making a html table from it? I mean the way like I would press file>email as attachment>attach as excel file?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to attach an xlsx file to an email using GAS.

Comment: I actually didn't check the page and was going forward so i came to this point so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334386 I don't really know how to use GAS, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the function getSheetById(id):

```
function getSheetById(id) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(
    function(s) {return s.getSheetId() === id;}
  )[0];
}
```